# Toggling between CSS display none and display block for a table column creates a weird border... why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Look at that weird border around the last column in the table...

[image]

The table looks like:

```
<table style="font-family: courier new; font-size: 0.75em" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tbody>
   <tr id="tableheader" class="">
      <th title="id">id</th>
      <th title="old_name">old_name</th>
      <th title="new_name">new_name</th>
      <th class="edit" title="Edit Options" style="display: block; overflow: hidden;">Edit Options</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="tableevenrow">
      <td data-col="id" valign="middle" align="left"><div>1</div></td>
      <td data-col="old_name" valign="middle" align="left"><div>taco</div></td>
      <td data-col="new_name" valign="middle" align="left"><div>bell</div></td>
      <td class="edit" data-col="editoptions" valign="middle" align="left" style="display: block; overflow: hidden;">
         <div class="row0 col3 col_editoptions">
            <div class="edit" style="display: block; overflow: hidden;">
               <select id="dropdown_0">
                  <option value="1">Confirm</option>
                  <option value="0">Decline</option>
               </select>
               <button id="submit_r0">Submit</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

and I have buttons that essentially just toggle between these two states:

```
        $('.edit').css('display','none'); 
        $('.norm').css('display','block'); 

        $('.edit').css('display','block'); 
        $('.norm').css('display','none');
```

So that when anything with the edit class is set to "none" then the whole "edit options" column is not shown at all on the screen.  This toggling works.  The only problem is that when the edit class is displayed, this column gets a weird border around it.  I was wondering if anyone knew why and how to fix it.  My buttons toggle visibility with the edit/norm classes below the table (they are in divs) but the border doesn't appear around them...

This is the css for the table styling... which is inherited (kind of) but I need to try and avoid changing this, even dynamically:

```
 body          { background: #e8ccbb; }
   .tableheader  { background: #4d4e86; color: #ffffff; }
   .tableoddrow  { background: #c2bad4; }
   .tableevenrow { background: #c2c3c2; }
   #tableheader  { background: #4d4e86; color: #ffffff }
   #tableoddrow  { background: #c2bad4 }
   #tableevenrow { background: #c2c3c2 }
   #hiliterow    { background: #ffffff }
   .menu_color {
      background:#4d4e86;
      background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#c2bad4),to(#4d4e86));
      background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#c2bad4,#4d4e86);
      background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#c2bad4,#4d4e86);
      background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#c2bad4,#4d4e86);
      background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#c2bad4,#4d4e86);
      background:linear-gradient(top,#c2bad4,#4d4e86)
   }
```

Also... side note... I am using PHP to make most of this happen and in no way would I describe my self as a front-end developer currently or in the past.... maybe future but who knows.

Comment: That's because you're triggering block display, but those should be `display: table-cell` instead.

Comment: ok.  so.... i need to toggle divs and the table column.  so... for the table hide/show-ing... i should go from display: table-cell and display-none...?

Comment: ok.  awesome.  it works.  do you want to post that as an answer or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're triggering block display, but those should be `display: table-cell` instead

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to use one button to show and hide the cells using jQuery `.toggle()`. It`s because you do not have to bother on what was "initial" display of toggling element - jQuery do it for you.

```
$('#my_button').click(function(){
    $('#el_to_toggle').toggle();
});
```

Implementation:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dr3Cm/

References:

- [jQuery .toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)